# Splash Screen's color is not updated by Night Mode

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

I am using XML method to implement my splash screen (To avoid that blank screen during cold start).
But the issue is that my background doesn't change with night mode it remains white.
Can anyone guide me out?

**res\drawable\splash_screenbg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/mainBG" />
    <!--
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/signin_img"/>
    </item>
    -->
</layer-list>
```

And My Theme / Theme- Night Resource file contains this style
**res\themes.xml**
or
**res\themes.xml(night)**

```
<!--Splash Screen-->
    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.StookPTU">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screenbg</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the Snippet from my Manifest File
**manifests\AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to colors.xml (**night**):

```
<color name="mainBG">#000000</color>
```

or change color to you custom color.